Numba njit making function call involving long expressions extremely slow
I am writing a finite volume code to solve the inviscid, compressible Euler equations. As a part of this, I am performing what is known as the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya process. A code snippet is given below
def cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dq_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dE_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], k: int, gamma: float) -> npt.NDArray:
    if k == 0:
        return np.array([drho_x[0], dq_x[0], dE_x[0]], dtype=np.float64)
    
    elif k == 1:
        rho_t = -dq_x[1]

        q_t = -dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**2) + 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]/(2*drho_x[0]**2) + dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0] - 3*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]/drho_x[0] - dE_x[1]*gamma + dE_x[1]

        E_t = -dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 + dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[1]/drho_x[0]**3 + 3*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**2) - 3*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]/(2*drho_x[0]**2) - dq_x[0]*dE_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0] + dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 - dq_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]

        return np.array([rho_t, q_t, E_t], dtype=np.float64)
    
    elif k == 2:
        

        rho_tt = dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[2]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**2) - 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[2]/(2*drho_x[0]**2) - dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 + 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]**2/drho_x[0]**3 + 2*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 - 6*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]/drho_x[0]**2 - dq_x[0]*dq_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0] + 3*dq_x[0]*dq_x[2]/drho_x[0] - dq_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0] + 3*dq_x[1]**2/drho_x[0] + dE_x[2]*gamma - dE_x[2]

        q_tt = dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[2]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 - 7*dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[2]/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - 3*dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[1]**2*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**4) - 3*dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0]**4 + 21*dq_x[0]**3*drho_x[1]**2/(2*drho_x[0]**4) + 5*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + 8*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 - 45*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[2]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**2) - 5*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[2]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**2) + 6*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[2]/drho_x[0]**2 - dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]**2*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 - 5*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + 12*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]**2/drho_x[0]**2 + 3*dq_x[0]*dE_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0] - 3*dq_x[0]*dE_x[2]/drho_x[0] - dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 - 2*dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + 3*dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]/drho_x[0]**2 - dq_x[0]*drho_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 + dq_x[0]*drho_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + 2*dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]**2*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**3 - 2*dq_x[0]*drho_x[1]**2*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 + dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma**2/drho_x[0] + 2*dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0] - 3*dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]/drho_x[0] - 2*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 + 2*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + dq_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/drho_x[0] - dq_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]

        E_tt = dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[2]*gamma**2/(4*drho_x[0]**4) + 2*dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0]**4 - 9*dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[2]/(4*drho_x[0]**4) - dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[1]**2*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**5 - 8*dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0]**5 + 9*dq_x[0]**4*drho_x[1]**2/drho_x[0]**5 + dq_x[0]**3*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**4 + 37*dq_x[0]**3*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**4) - 39*dq_x[0]**3*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]/(2*drho_x[0]**4) - 7*dq_x[0]**3*dq_x[2]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + 7*dq_x[0]**3*dq_x[2]/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - 21*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]**2*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + 21*dq_x[0]**2*dq_x[1]**2/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - dq_x[0]**2*dE_x[2]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**2) + 3*dq_x[0]**2*dE_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 - 3*dq_x[0]**2*dE_x[2]/(2*drho_x[0]**2) + dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - 15*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]*dE_x[1]/drho_x[0]**3 - dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**3) - 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**3) + 3*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]**2*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/(2*drho_x[0]**4) + 9*dq_x[0]**2*drho_x[1]**2*dE_x[0]*gamma/(2*drho_x[0]**4) - dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 + 8*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 - 3*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*dE_x[1]/drho_x[0]**2 - dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**3 - 7*dq_x[0]*dq_x[1]*drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**3 + 2*dq_x[0]*dq_x[2]*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + 2*dq_x[1]**2*dE_x[0]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2 + dE_x[0]*dE_x[2]*gamma**2/drho_x[0] - dE_x[0]*dE_x[2]*gamma/drho_x[0] + dE_x[1]**2*gamma**2/drho_x[0] - dE_x[1]**2*gamma/drho_x[0] - drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*dE_x[1]*gamma**2/drho_x[0]**2 + drho_x[1]*dE_x[0]*dE_x[1]*gamma/drho_x[0]**2


        return np.array([rho_tt, q_tt, E_tt], dtype=np.float64)


    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid order")


There are also statements for k = 3, 4, and 5 which I have excluded for brevity. Suffice to say that these lines become longer and longer (80000+ characters in a line) with loads of similar memory accesses, powers, and multiplications like above.
When I use njit with this code, a) it is slower than without njit (for k = 5 the difference is 500 to 600 times), and b) it gets slower and slower the higher the k I include elif statements for, regardless of which k I am evaluating the function for. As far as I can tell, there should be nothing in the function which makes the performance using Numba so bad.

are you timing the first time you call the function? if so, you are also timing the compilation time.

@Nin17 this function call is a small part of a much bigger code. I'm not timing the function call itself but if I could tell you how long it takes to run the entire code with and without njit, for the case where k = 5, without njit is about a minute and with njit is 600 minutes.

Can the equations be simplified to reduce the number of operations? Can you define commonly used terms to reuse (such as drho_x_inv = 1/drho_x[0] so you aren't computing the same value over and over again)? Just because it's compiled doesn't necessarily mean you can get away with writing "naive" code (i.e. you might have to do some of your own optimizations).

@jared Compilers can do that themselves though it helps Numba to generate less code to LLVM (which is flooded by the number of generated instructions) and doing this faster (because Numba is written in Python which is slow) only speeding up the build in the end, not the execution time (especially with fastmath=True).

With all due respect, the (cit.) "(...) lines become longer and longer (80000+ characters in a line)" is actually a self-evidenced anti-pattern of wrong approach to code for a performance. Revised code shall avoid thousands of principally wasted operations, that algebra does its job before coding repetitive (expensive) operations to happen many times, instead of properly reduced formulas with smart precomputed constants. If performance was the goal the code shall never look like this. After 20+ years in ultra-low latency+high-throughput designs I dare claim a reduced code (on FPGA) wins

How is this code generated? Is this the result of some code generation, maybe SymPy? In most code generators like Sympy there is a common subexpression elimination, to avoid such huge codes automatically if there are common subexpressions. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#module-sympy.simplify.cse_main

@jared, yes I'm sure that I could do some kind of simplifications and I will redo my code so that it takes those things into account

@user3666197, ideally I would have done some precomputation as you suggested, but for example once I reach something like k = 5, there are significantly more values to precompute. That said, I will certainly look into ways to make the code more efficient

@max9111, Yes this is generated using SymPy! I will try to apply the common subexpression elimination as you suggest to make the code more efficient

TL;DR: you should avoid providing such a big code directly to Numba and compile the caller function with Numba. If you cannot, the only possible optimization is to pre-allocate the output (or actually not to use Numba but C extension directly without checking inputs -- which is unsafe).

Optimizing the compilation time
First of all, the compiled code is pretty huge, especially if the same logic is applied "for k = 3, 4, and 5". This is a problem for 2 reasons. Firstly, the bigger the code to compile, the slower it takes to build. Secondly, large compiled codes are still not optimal because the native compiled code needs to be fetched from the cache/RAM, decoded and then executed. The first two steps are expensive, especially when the code is large. Thus, loops can be faster sometimes because of the two first overheads.
To be sure the compilation time is not a problem in the middle of your benchmark/application (due to a lazy compilation), you can compile the function eagerly by providing the target signature of the function. Note that Numba does not care about types annotations like npt.NDArray[np.float64] currently. Here is an example of signature:
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], int64, float64)')

On my machine, the functions takes 3.74 seconds to build. This is a lot for such a simple computing function and a significant time should be spent in the Numba Python code parsing and semantic analysis. While this time is paid only once when the function is defined thanks to the eager compilation, slowing down the initialization of your program so much is not reasonable to me. The key is to avoid replicated expression. Note this does not impact much the execution time of the compiled function because compilers (like Numba) can analyses replicated terms and avoid recomputing things. Also note that this makes the code more readable too (avoiding ugly lines of >1700 characters). Here is a bit better version:
def cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dq_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dE_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], k: int, gamma: float) -> npt.NDArray:
    g = gamma
    r0, r1, r2 = drho_x
    q0, q1, q2 = dq_x
    e0, e1, e2 = dE_x

    r0p2, r1p2 = r0**2, r1**2
    q0p2, q1p2 = q0**2, q1**2
    e0p2, e1p2 = e0**2, e1**2
    gp2 = g**2
    r0p3, r0p4 = r0**3, r0**4
    q0p3, q0p4 = q0**3, q0**4

    if k == 0:
        return np.array([r0, q0, e0], dtype=np.float64)
    
    elif k == 1:
        rho_t = -q1
        q_t = -q0p2*r1*g/(2*r0p2) + 3*q0p2*r1/(2*r0p2) + q0*q1*g/r0 - 3*q0*q1/r0 - e1*g + e1
        E_t = -q0p3*r1*g/r0p3 + q0p3*r1/r0p3 + 3*q0p2*q1*g/(2*r0p2) - 3*q0p2*q1/(2*r0p2) - q0*e1*g/r0 + q0*r1*e0*g/r0p2 - q1*e0*g/r0
        return np.array([rho_t, q_t, E_t], dtype=np.float64)
    
    elif k == 2:
        rho_tt = q0p2*r2*g/(2*r0p2) - 3*q0p2*r2/(2*r0p2) - q0p2*r1p2*g/r0p3 + 3*q0p2*r1p2/r0p3 + 2*q0*q1*r1*g/r0p2 - 6*q0*q1*r1/r0p2 - q0*q2*g/r0 + 3*q0*q2/r0 - q1p2*g/r0 + 3*q1p2/r0 + e2*g - e2
        q_tt = q0p3*r2*gp2/(2*r0p3) + q0p3*r2*g/r0p3 - 7*q0p3*r2/(2*r0p3) - 3*q0p3*r1p2*gp2/(2*r0p4) - 3*q0p3*r1p2*g/r0p4 + 21*q0p3*r1p2/(2*r0p4) + 5*q0p2*q1*r1*gp2/(2*r0p3) + 8*q0p2*q1*r1*g/r0p3 - 45*q0p2*q1*r1/(2*r0p3) - q0p2*q2*gp2/(2*r0p2) - 5*q0p2*q2*g/(2*r0p2) + 6*q0p2*q2/r0p2 - q0*q1p2*gp2/r0p2 - 5*q0*q1p2*g/r0p2 + 12*q0*q1p2/r0p2 + 3*q0*e2*g/r0 - 3*q0*e2/r0 - q0*r1*e1*gp2/r0p2 - 2*q0*r1*e1*g/r0p2 + 3*q0*r1*e1/r0p2 - q0*r2*e0*gp2/r0p2 + q0*r2*e0*g/r0p2 + 2*q0*r1p2*e0*gp2/r0p3 - 2*q0*r1p2*e0*g/r0p3 + q1*e1*gp2/r0 + 2*q1*e1*g/r0 - 3*q1*e1/r0 - 2*q1*r1*e0*gp2/r0p2 + 2*q1*r1*e0*g/r0p2 + q2*e0*gp2/r0 - q2*e0*g/r0
        E_tt = q0p4*r2*gp2/(4*r0p4) + 2*q0p4*r2*g/r0p4 - 9*q0p4*r2/(4*r0p4) - q0p4*r1p2*gp2/r0**5 - 8*q0p4*r1p2*g/r0**5 + 9*q0p4*r1p2/r0**5 + q0p3*q1*r1*gp2/r0p4 + 37*q0p3*q1*r1*g/(2*r0p4) - 39*q0p3*q1*r1/(2*r0p4) - 7*q0p3*q2*g/(2*r0p3) + 7*q0p3*q2/(2*r0p3) - 21*q0p2*q1p2*g/(2*r0p3) + 21*q0p2*q1p2/(2*r0p3) - q0p2*e2*gp2/(2*r0p2) + 3*q0p2*e2*g/r0p2 - 3*q0p2*e2/(2*r0p2) + q0p2*r1*e1*gp2/(2*r0p3) - 15*q0p2*r1*e1*g/(2*r0p3) + 3*q0p2*r1*e1/r0p3 - q0p2*r2*e0*gp2/(2*r0p3) - 3*q0p2*r2*e0*g/(2*r0p3) + 3*q0p2*r1p2*e0*gp2/(2*r0p4) + 9*q0p2*r1p2*e0*g/(2*r0p4) - q0*q1*e1*gp2/r0p2 + 8*q0*q1*e1*g/r0p2 - 3*q0*q1*e1/r0p2 - q0*q1*r1*e0*gp2/r0p3 - 7*q0*q1*r1*e0*g/r0p3 + 2*q0*q2*e0*g/r0p2 + 2*q1p2*e0*g/r0p2 + e0*e2*gp2/r0 - e0*e2*g/r0 + e1p2*gp2/r0 - e1p2*g/r0 - r1*e0*e1*gp2/r0p2 + r1*e0*e1*g/r0p2
        return np.array([rho_tt, q_tt, E_tt], dtype=np.float64)

    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid order")

It is still far from being great but I cannot find a generic pattern for all sub-expressions (it is simpler to develop an expression than to factorize it).
This function takes 1.55 second to build on my machine (with the same execution time). This is a 2.4 faster build.
You can reduce this overhead further using the compilation flag cache=True.

Setup and Benchmark
Here is the setup used to measure the performance of your code:
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import numba as nb

%%time
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], int64, float64)')
def cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dq_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], dE_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], k: int, gamma: float) -> npt.NDArray:
    # [...]

drho_x = np.random.rand(3)
dq_x = np.random.rand(3)
dE_x = np.random.rand(3)
gamma = 42.0
%timeit -n 20_000 cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x, dq_x, dE_x, 0, gamma)
%timeit -n 20_000 cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x, dq_x, dE_x, 1, gamma)
%timeit -n 20_000 cauchyKovalevskaya(drho_x, dq_x, dE_x, 2, gamma)

Regarding the execution time, here is the timings on my machine (with an eager compilation):
1.27 µs ± 8.18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
1.28 µs ± 16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
1.37 µs ± 24.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)


Performance Analysis and Solutions
>90% of the time comes from overheads (like creating the output array, checking the input types and converting them to native types, calling a native function from CPython) and not computation. Pre-allocating the output helps to reduce the execution time a bit. That being said, there is no way to massively reduce the execution time as long as this function is called from CPython. This is the main bottleneck. You can compile the caller function with Numba to significantly reduce this overhead.
On my machine, it looks like the computation takes only 0.1 µs.
Once the caller function is compiled with Numba, note you can add the compilation flag fastmath=True so to accelerate math computations. That being said, this option is harmful if values can be NaN, -inf, +inf, sub-normals, or even if the associativity of the operation matters. For more information about this, please read this post. I do not recommend it in this case because I do not expect a huge speed up on the modified code.

+1 Correct - Overheads matter ( the njit()-ed code pays more, irreducible overheads, than the technical JIT-compiled code can save in return ). As dynamical systems are "serial"-in time (seq. of steps in time are mutually ( linearly ) dependent, there is zero chance to vectorize or gain any other sort of performance boost. Last but not least, ol' days control-systems / HFT tricks can help: precompute all constants+avoid DIV-s at 0(1) costs ( try to find any internal dependencies for re-using partial results on the fly, not to pay same costs more than once ). No other magics or tricks avaialble


Q :"Numba njit making function call involving long expressions extremely slow"

With all due respect no, let's not blame an arrow we used for missing the fish.
Finite volume methods typically iterate in time over some 2-D or 3-D domains, so the posted code will be called immense amount of times. No matter how inefficient was the originally drafted code, in principle nothing but a k-switched return()-one-liner ( though calling an about 250 [kB] SLOC a one-liner is not so common, yet the as-is code was such designed ), the fact of entering an awfully many-times called part of finite volume computation makes more troubles outside, then was revealed inside the def-ed method.
Overheads matter. For many-times called code ALL overheads matter.
Numba JIT-compiled trick will come at some additional costs ( an initial cost of compilation + additional per-call overheads ), so unless you design the calling code better, you soon realised you keep paying way more on add-on overhead costs, then you will ever receive in any ( potential only ) speed-up.
Why?
Besides the irreducible overheads, you also pay extra time for things you could do smarter. The overhead add-on costs paid for each return() to instantiate ALAP a fresh new Numpy object, initialise it, allocate new memory so as to move just 3 scalars, is technically bad. Last but not least, your calculation code actually repeats so many time fragments of calculations, that was not needed to be done this way and so many times again at all.
How better?
We know we can do in principle about 30x ADD-, SUB-uops or about 10x MUL-uops during a time a one single DIV-uop gets computed, so DIV-s are the most expensive elementary operations ( the more are sqrt() or **0.5 et al ), so when speaking about performance, about HIGH PERFORMANCE, we may avoid DIV-s by smarter MUL-s.
Next comes the art of algebra ( for possibilities see the mock-up code below ),not only to reduce 80'000 bytes long assignments, but also to set smarter the dependency-tree calculations, so as to avoid repeating and repeating evaluation of values we have already computed ( do not expect magic from compiler optimizations, these are smart, but for other things than transforming the  80'000 bytes of the posted time-derivated equations into algebraically equivalent, more efficient calculi ).

Q :(cit.) "(...) lines become longer and longer (80000+ characters in a line)"

The line span is not the sole root cause of the problem, their algebraical inefficiency is.
Enclosed is a commented revision of code, that demonstrates the re-factoring intent - finding self-repeating fragments, redesign a use of DIV-avoiding, MUL-efficient reformulation, to compute the same, while re-using many times those values, that appear many times inside the equations :
def cauchyKovalevskaya( drho_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
                          dq_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
                          dE_x: npt.NDArray[np.float64],
                             k: int,
                        #gamma: float
                             g: float
                              ) -> npt.NDArray:
    
    if k == 0:                                                          ## JIT/RET --^         non-MISRA-C
        return np.array([drho_x[0],
                           dq_x[0],
                           dE_x[0]
                           ],
                        dtype=np.float64)                               ## rather expensive to instantiate a fresh new instance, initialise and allocate memory ALAP so as to return just 3 scalars
    
    if k == 1:
        #g         = gamma
        gp2        = g**2
        
        r0, r1, r2 = drho_x
        q0, q1, q2 = dq_x
        e0, e1, e2 = dE_x
        
        r0p2, r1p2 = r0**2,   r1**2
        
        #0p3, r0p4 = r0**3,   r0**4
        r0p3, r0p4 = r0*r0p2, r0p2*r0p2
        
        q0p2, q1p2 = q0**2, q1**2
        e0p2, e1p2 = e0**2, e1**2
        
        
        q0p3, q0p4 = q0**3, q0**4

        ##--------------------------------------------------------------##---------------------------------------##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------( per-call consts )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0___DIV_r0       1x DIV   VALUE REUSED: 8x
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2     1x MUL                 3x
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0p3_DIV_r0p3     1x MUL                 ?  ( MUL var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2, var_q0___DIV_r0 )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## 
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                           var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2
        rho_t =             -q1                                         ##                                       ##                                    /
        q_t   =  (    -q0p2        *r1                *g / (2*r0p2)     ## ~~ constA * r1 * q0p2 / r0p2          ## constA ~ -g/2   \_____ ( r1 * q0p2/r0p2 )*((3-g)/2) ... constAB (( 3 - g )*0.5 )
                 + 3 * q0p2        *r1                   / (2*r0p2)     ## ~~ constB * r1 * q0p2 / r0p2          ## constB ~ +3/2   /
                 +     q0   *q1                       *g /    r0        ## ~~ constC *      q0*q1/ r0            ## constC ~ +g     \_____ ( q1 * q0  /r0   )*( g - 3 ) ... constCD
                 - 3 * q0   *q1                          /    r0        ## ~~ constD *      q0*q1/ r0            ## constD ~ -3     /
                 -                               e1   *g                ## ~~ constE *                   e1      ## constE ~ -g     \_____ e1 *               ( 1 - g ) ... constEF
                 +                               e1                     ## ~~ constF *                   e1      ## constF ~ +1     /
                   )                                                    ##---------------------------------------##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## 
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                      (  var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2 
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                      *  var_q0___DIV_r0   )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                                  /
        E_t   =  (    -q0p3        *r1                *g /    r0p3      ## ~~ constG * r1 * q0p3 / r0p3          ## constG ~ -g     \_____ r1 * q0p3/r0p3 * ( 1 - g ) ... constEF
                 +     q0p3        *r1                   /    r0p3      ## ~~ constH * r1 * q0p3 / r0p3          ## constH ~ +1     /
                 + 3 * q0p2 *q1                       *g / (2*r0p2)     ## ~~ constI * q1 * q0p2 / r0p2          ## constI ~ +3g/2                    \____ q1 * q0p2 / r0p2 * ( 3/2 * ( g - 1 ) ) ... constIJ
                 - 3 * q0p2 *q1                          / (2*r0p2)     ## ~~ constJ * q1 * q0p2 / r0p2          ## constJ ~ -3/2 == -constB          /
                 -     q0                       *e1   *g /    r0        ## ~~ constK *      q0   / r0   *e1      ## constK ~ -g   == -constC == constE         g *               e1 * q0 / r0
                 +     q0          *r1       *e0      *g /    r0p2      ## ~~ constL * r1 * q0   / r0p2 *e0      ## constL ~ +g   ==  constC          \____    g * e0 / r0   * ( r1 * q0 / r0 - q1 )
                 -           q1              *e0      *g /    r0        ## ~~ constM * q1        / r0   *e0      ## constM ~ -g   == -constC == constE/
                   )
        return np.array([rho_t, q_t, E_t], dtype=np.float64)            ## rather expensive to instantiate a fresh new instance, initialise and allocate memory ALAP so as to return just 3 scalars
    
    elif k == 2:
        #g         = gamma
        gp2        = g**2
        
        r0, r1, r2 = drho_x
        q0, q1, q2 = dq_x
        e0, e1, e2 = dE_x
        
        r0p2, r1p2 = r0**2,   r1**2
        
        #0p3, r0p4 = r0**3,   r0**4
        #0p3, r0p4 = r0*r0p2, r0p2*r0p2
        
        q0p2, q1p2 = q0**2, q1**2
        e0p2, e1p2 = e0**2, e1**2
        
        q0p3, q0p4 = q0**3, q0**4

        ##--------------------------------------------------------------##---------------------------------------##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------( per-call consts )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var______DIV_r0       1x DIV   VALUE REUSED: 2x
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0___DIV_r0       1x MUL                 2x (+MUL var_q0___DIV_r0,   var______DIV_r0 ~ q0/r0p2 )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2     1x MUL                 2x
        ##                                                              ##                                       ## var_q0p3_DIV_r0p3     1x MUL                 ?  ( MUL var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2, var_q0___DIV_r0 )
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                             
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                          var_q0p2_DIV_r0p2
        ##                                                              ##                                       ##                                   /
        rho_tt = (     q0p2              *r2            *g / (2*r0p2)   ## ~~ const * r2 * q0p2 / r0p2           ## const   ~ +g/2 \_____ ( r2 * q0p2/r0p2 ) *((g-3)*0.5) ... constAB2
                 - 3 * q0p2              *r2               / (2*r0p2)   ## ~~ const * r2 * q0p2 / r0p2           ##         ~ -3/2 / 
                 -     q0p2        *r1p2                *g /    r0p3    ##                                                         \_____ ( r1p2*q0p2/r0p2/r0)*(  3 - g ) 
                 + 3 * q0p2        *r1p2                   /    r0p3    ##                                                         /                                     \
                 + 2 * q0   *q1    *r1                  *g /    r0p2    ##                                                         \_____ ( r1 * q0  /r0p2*q1)*(2*g - 6 ) \
                 - 6 * q0   *q1    *r1                     /    r0p2    ##                                                         /                                       \
                 -     q0       *q2                     *g /    r0      ##                                                         \_____ (      q0  /r0  *q2)*(  3 - g ) --+---- ( 3 - g ) * ( (...) + (...) + (...) )
                 + 3 * q0       *q2                        /    r0      ##                                                         /                                       /
                 -           q1p2                       *g /    r0      ##                                                         \_____ (      q1p2/r0     )*(  3 - g ) /
                 + 3 *       q1p2                          /    r0      ##                                                         /
                 +                                  e2  *g              ##                                                         \_____ (                e2)*(  g - 1 ) 
                 -                                  e2                  ##                                                         /
                   )                            
                                                
        q_tt   = (     q0p3              *r2           *gp2/ (2*r0p3)
                 +     q0p3              *r2           *g  /    r0p3
                 - 7 * q0p3              *r2               / (2*r0p3)
                 - 3 * q0p3        *r1p2               *gp2/ (2*r0p4)
                 - 3 * q0p3        *r1p2               *g  /    r0p4
                 +21 * q0p3        *r1p2                   / (2*r0p4)
                 + 5 * q0p2 *q1    *r1                 *gp2/ (2*r0p3)
                 + 8 * q0p2 *q1    *r1                 *g  /    r0p3
                 -45 * q0p2 *q1    *r1                     / (2*r0p3)
                 -     q0p2     *q2                    *gp2/ (2*r0p2)
                 - 5 * q0p2     *q2                    *g  / (2*r0p2)
                 + 6 * q0p2     *q2                        /    r0p2
                 -     q0   *q1p2                      *gp2/    r0p2
                 - 5 * q0   *q1p2                      *g  /    r0p2
                 +12 * q0   *q1p2                          /    r0p2
                 + 3 * q0                          *e2 *g  /    r0
                 - 3 * q0                          *e2     /    r0
                 -     q0           *r1         *e1    *gp2/    r0p2
                 - 2 * q0           *r1         *e1    *g  /    r0p2
                 + 3 * q0           *r1         *e1        /    r0p2
                 -     q0                *r2 *e0       *gp2/    r0p2
                 +     q0                *r2 *e0       *g  /    r0p2
                 + 2 * q0           *r1p2    *e0       *gp2/    r0p3
                 - 2 * q0           *r1p2    *e0       *g  /    r0p3
                 +          q1                  *e1    *gp2/    r0
                 + 2       *q1                  *e1    *g  /    r0
                 - 3       *q1                  *e1        /    r0
                 - 2       *q1      *r1      *e0       *gp2/    r0p2
                 + 2       *q1      *r1      *e0       *g  /    r0p2
                 +               q2          *e0       *gp2/    r0
                 -               q2          *e0       *g  /    r0
                   )
        E_tt   = (   q0p4*r2*gp2/(4*r0p4)
                 + 2*q0p4*r2*g/r0p4
                 - 9*q0p4*r2/(4*r0p4)
                 -   q0p4*r1p2*gp2/r0**5
                 - 8*q0p4*r1p2*g/r0**5
                 + 9*q0p4*r1p2/r0**5
                 +   q0p3*q1*r1*gp2/r0p4
                 +37*q0p3*q1*r1*g/(2*r0p4)
                 -39*q0p3*q1*r1/(2*r0p4)
                 - 7*q0p3*q2*g/(2*r0p3)
                 + 7*q0p3*q2/(2*r0p3)
                 -21*q0p2*q1p2*g/(2*r0p3)
                 +21*q0p2*q1p2/(2*r0p3)
                 -   q0p2*e2*gp2/(2*r0p2)
                 + 3*q0p2*e2*g/r0p2
                 - 3*q0p2*e2/(2*r0p2)
                 +   q0p2*r1*e1*gp2/(2*r0p3)
                 -15*q0p2*r1*e1*g/(2*r0p3)
                 + 3*q0p2*r1*e1/r0p3
                 -   q0p2*r2*e0*gp2/(2*r0p3)
                 - 3*q0p2*r2*e0*g/(2*r0p3)
                 + 3*q0p2*r1p2*e0*gp2/(2*r0p4)
                 + 9*q0p2*r1p2*e0*g/(2*r0p4)
                 -   q0*q1*e1*gp2/r0p2
                 + 8*q0*q1*e1*g/r0p2
                 - 3*q0*q1*e1/r0p2
                 -   q0*q1*r1*e0*gp2/r0p3
                 - 7*q0*q1*r1*e0*g/r0p3
                 + 2*q0*q2*e0*g/r0p2
                 + 2*q1p2*e0*g/r0p2
                 +     e0*e2*gp2/r0
                 -     e0*e2*g/r0
                 +     e1p2*gp2/r0
                 -     e1p2*g/r0
                 - r1*e0*e1*gp2/r0p2
                 + r1*e0*e1*g/r0p2
                   )
        
        return np.array([rho_tt, q_tt, E_tt], dtype=np.float64)         ## rather expensive to instantiate a fresh new instance, initialise and allocate memory ALAP so as to return just 3 scalars

    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid order")


My goal was never to blame Numba! I wanted to know what was wrong with my code that was causing it to optimise so poorly. But your answer sheds light on some things which would be quite useful to change in the code.

Glad you have found it inspirative. The beauty of ultimate performance comes from respecting technical details. Good luck in your research & stay tuned, surprises are always to come along our interesting work, @SiddharthYajaman

Congratulations on having the courage to factorize the expression (I did not even tried)! That being said, "we can do in principle about 30x ADD-, SUB-uops or about 10x MUL-uops during a time a one single DIV-uop gets computed" is not true anymore on mainstream CPUs (since >10 years) on scalar FP64 numbers. For example, regarding the instruction throughput (which matter the most here), Intel CPUs can do 2 addsd/subsd/mulsd per cycle and a divsd takes 3 cycles/item. Thus, FP64 multiplications are as fast as an FP64 additions/subtractions, and divisions are only 6 times slower (not 30).

The statement is approximately valid for integers though (not used on the OP's code): on mainstream x86 CPUs, a mul is typically 4x slower than a add/sub, and a div is >10x (dependent of the number of bits of the integer -- often slower for 64-bit ones).
